# Health State does not change in SCOM

Tags: c#, .net, scom, system-center

Our SCOM version is `7.3.13142.0`

We have developed Management Pack for SCOM integration.

Please review Management Pack source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><ManagementPack ContentReadable="true" SchemaVersion="2.0" OriginalSchemaVersion="1.0" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <Manifest>
    <Identity>
      <ID>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring</ID>
      <Version>1.0.0.0</Version>
    </Identity>
    <Name>CloudMonix Resource Monitoring Pack</Name>
    <References>
      <Reference Alias="System">
        <ID>System.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.5.8501.0</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="Health">
        <ID>System.Health.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.0.8438.6</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
      <Reference Alias="SystemCenter">
        <ID>Microsoft.SystemCenter.Library</ID>
        <Version>7.0.8438.6</Version>
        <PublicKeyToken>31bf3856ad364e35</PublicKeyToken>
      </Reference>
    </References>
  </Manifest>
  <TypeDefinitions>
    <EntityTypes>
      <ClassTypes>
        <ClassType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" Accessibility="Public" Abstract="false" Base="System!System.Entity" Hosted="false" Singleton="false" Extension="false">
          <Property ID="ResourceId" Type="string" AutoIncrement="false" Key="true" CaseSensitive="false" MaxLength="256" MinLength="1" Required="false" Scale="0" />
          <Property ID="ResourceType" Type="string" AutoIncrement="false" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" MaxLength="256" MinLength="1" Required="false" Scale="0" />
          <Property ID="ResourceGroups" Type="string" AutoIncrement="false" Key="false" CaseSensitive="false" MaxLength="1024" MinLength="1" Required="false" Scale="0" />
        </ClassType>
      </ClassTypes>
    </EntityTypes>
    <ModuleTypes>
      <WriteActionModuleType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.SetStateAction" Accessibility="Internal" Batching="false">
        <Configuration>
          <IncludeSchemaTypes>
            <SchemaType>Health!System.Health.AlertSchema</SchemaType>
          </IncludeSchemaTypes>
          <xsd:element name="ManagementGroupId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element name="MonitorId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element name="ManagedEntityId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element name="HealthState" type="System.Health.AlertHealthState" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <ModuleImplementation Isolation="Any">
          <Native>
            <ClassID>44cbc334-8b5f-4cb6-bee0-6bdcbc80e8d5</ClassID>
          </Native>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <InputType>System!System.BaseData</InputType>
      </WriteActionModuleType>
      <WriteActionModuleType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetStateAction" Accessibility="Internal" Batching="false">
        <Configuration>
          <IncludeSchemaTypes>
            <SchemaType>Health!System.Health.AlertSchema</SchemaType>
          </IncludeSchemaTypes>
          <xsd:element name="MonitorId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
          <xsd:element name="HealthState" type="System.Health.AlertHealthState" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <ModuleImplementation Isolation="Any">
          <Composite>
            <MemberModules>
              <WriteAction ID="WA" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.SetStateAction">
                <ManagementGroupId>$Target/ManagementGroup/Id$</ManagementGroupId>
                <MonitorId>$Config/MonitorId$</MonitorId>
                <ManagedEntityId>$Data/ManagedEntityId$</ManagedEntityId>
                <HealthState>$Config/HealthState$</HealthState>
              </WriteAction>
            </MemberModules>
            <Composition>
              <Node ID="WA" />
            </Composition>
          </Composite>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <InputType>System!System.BaseData</InputType>
      </WriteActionModuleType>
      <WriteActionModuleType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetSuccessAction" Accessibility="Public" Batching="false">
        <Configuration>
          <xsd:element name="MonitorId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <ModuleImplementation Isolation="Any">
          <Composite>
            <MemberModules>
              <WriteAction ID="WA" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetStateAction">
                <MonitorId>$Config/MonitorId$</MonitorId>
                <HealthState>Success</HealthState>
              </WriteAction>
            </MemberModules>
            <Composition>
              <Node ID="WA" />
            </Composition>
          </Composite>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <InputType>System!System.BaseData</InputType>
      </WriteActionModuleType>
      <WriteActionModuleType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetWarningAction" Accessibility="Public" Batching="false">
        <Configuration>
          <xsd:element name="MonitorId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <ModuleImplementation Isolation="Any">
          <Composite>
            <MemberModules>
              <WriteAction ID="WA" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetStateAction">
                <MonitorId>$Config/MonitorId$</MonitorId>
                <HealthState>Warning</HealthState>
              </WriteAction>
            </MemberModules>
            <Composition>
              <Node ID="WA" />
            </Composition>
          </Composite>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <InputType>System!System.BaseData</InputType>
      </WriteActionModuleType>
      <WriteActionModuleType ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetErrorAction" Accessibility="Public" Batching="false">
        <Configuration>
          <xsd:element name="MonitorId" type="xsd:string" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" />
        </Configuration>
        <ModuleImplementation Isolation="Any">
          <Composite>
            <MemberModules>
              <WriteAction ID="WA" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetStateAction">
                <MonitorId>$Config/MonitorId$</MonitorId>
                <HealthState>Error</HealthState>
              </WriteAction>
            </MemberModules>
            <Composition>
              <Node ID="WA" />
            </Composition>
          </Composite>
        </ModuleImplementation>
        <InputType>System!System.BaseData</InputType>
      </WriteActionModuleType>
    </ModuleTypes>
  </TypeDefinitions>
  <Monitoring>
    <Rules>
      <Rule ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor.Success" Enabled="true" Target="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.RootManagementServer" ConfirmDelivery="false" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal" DiscardLevel="100">
        <Category>StateCollection</Category>
        <DataSources>
          <DataSource ID="DataSource" TypeID="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.SdkEventProvider" />
        </DataSources>
        <ConditionDetection ID="ConditionDetection" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter">
          <Expression>
            <SimpleExpression>
              <ValueExpression>
                <XPathQuery>EventNumber</XPathQuery>
              </ValueExpression>
              <Operator>Equal</Operator>
              <ValueExpression>
                <Value>1</Value>
              </ValueExpression>
            </SimpleExpression>
          </Expression>
        </ConditionDetection>
        <WriteActions>
          <WriteAction ID="WriteAction" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetSuccessAction">
            <MonitorId>$MPElement[Name="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor"]$</MonitorId>
          </WriteAction>
        </WriteActions>
      </Rule>
      <Rule ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor.Warning" Enabled="true" Target="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.RootManagementServer" ConfirmDelivery="false" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal" DiscardLevel="100">
        <Category>StateCollection</Category>
        <DataSources>
          <DataSource ID="DataSource" TypeID="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.SdkEventProvider" />
        </DataSources>
        <ConditionDetection ID="ConditionDetection" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter">
          <Expression>
            <SimpleExpression>
              <ValueExpression>
                <XPathQuery>EventNumber</XPathQuery>
              </ValueExpression>
              <Operator>Equal</Operator>
              <ValueExpression>
                <Value>2</Value>
              </ValueExpression>
            </SimpleExpression>
          </Expression>
        </ConditionDetection>
        <WriteActions>
          <WriteAction ID="WriteAction" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetWarningAction">
            <MonitorId>$MPElement[Name="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor"]$</MonitorId>
          </WriteAction>
        </WriteActions>
      </Rule>
      <Rule ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor.Error" Enabled="true" Target="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.RootManagementServer" ConfirmDelivery="false" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal" DiscardLevel="100">
        <Category>StateCollection</Category>
        <DataSources>
          <DataSource ID="DataSource" TypeID="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.SdkEventProvider" />
        </DataSources>
        <ConditionDetection ID="ConditionDetection" TypeID="System!System.ExpressionFilter">
          <Expression>
            <SimpleExpression>
              <ValueExpression>
                <XPathQuery>EventNumber</XPathQuery>
              </ValueExpression>
              <Operator>Equal</Operator>
              <ValueExpression>
                <Value>3</Value>
              </ValueExpression>
            </SimpleExpression>
          </Expression>
        </ConditionDetection>
        <WriteActions>
          <WriteAction ID="WriteAction" TypeID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.TargetSetErrorAction">
            <MonitorId>$MPElement[Name="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor"]$</MonitorId>
          </WriteAction>
        </WriteActions>
      </Rule>
    </Rules>
    <Monitors>
      <AggregateMonitor ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="true" Target="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" ParentMonitorID="Health!System.Health.EntityState" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal">
        <Category>StateCollection</Category>
        <Algorithm>WorstOf</Algorithm>
      </AggregateMonitor>
    </Monitors>
  </Monitoring>
  <Presentation>
    <Views>
      <View ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" Accessibility="Public" Enabled="true" Target="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" TypeID="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.StateViewType" Visible="true">
        <Category>Operations</Category>
        <Criteria>
          <InMaintenanceMode>false</InMaintenanceMode>
        </Criteria>
        <Presentation>
          <ColumnInfo Index="0" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="true" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>State</Name>
            <Id>CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="1" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Type</Name>
            <Id>ResourceType</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="2" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Name</Name>
            <Id>DisplayName</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
          <ColumnInfo Index="3" SortIndex="-1" Width="100" Grouped="false" Sorted="false" IsSortable="true" Visible="true" SortOrder="Ascending">
            <Name>Resource Groups</Name>
            <Id>ResourceGroups</Id>
          </ColumnInfo>
        </Presentation>
        <Target />
      </View>
    </Views>
    <Folders>
      <Folder ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder" Accessibility="Public" ParentFolder="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.Monitoring.ViewFolder.Root" />
    </Folders>
    <FolderItems>
      <FolderItem ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView" Folder="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder" />
    </FolderItems>
  </Presentation>
  <LanguagePacks>
    <LanguagePack ID="ENU" IsDefault="false">
      <DisplayStrings>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource Monitoring</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainFolder">
          <Name>CloudMonix Folder</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.MainView">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource View</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor">
          <Name>CloudMonix Health State Monitor</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource">
          <Name>CloudMonix Resource</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceId">
          <Name>Resource Id</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceType">
          <Name>Resource Type</Name>
        </DisplayString>
        <DisplayString ElementID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource" SubElementID="ResourceGroups">
          <Name>Resource Groups</Name>
        </DisplayString>
      </DisplayStrings>
    </LanguagePack>
  </LanguagePacks>
</ManagementPack>
```

We try to change Health State for monitored resources in this Pack.
We implemented 3 state as described in Jakub Oleksy [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jakuboleksy/2007/08/22/setting-the-state-of-an-instance-programmatically/).

We send data to SCOM using .NET [SDK](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh329086.aspx).
And all works fine... We can see Performance data and events.

But unfortunately Health State does not change.

Of course we have cleared Health State cache, reboot server, etc.
But there no results.

Please ask me about any additional information which I can provide to solve the trouble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have fixed this trouble.

We had problem with Target Rule:

```
<Rule ID="CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Monitor.Error" Enabled="true" Target="SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.RootManagementServer" ConfirmDelivery="false" Remotable="true" Priority="Normal" DiscardLevel="100">
```

We have used **SystemCenter!Microsoft.SystemCenter.RootManagementServer** target. This target is invalid for our environment.

We changed Target to **CloudMonix.ResourceMonitoring.Resource**.
And now the Health State change correctly.

You can see details on Jakub Oleksy [article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jakuboleksy/2007/08/22/setting-the-state-of-an-instance-programmatically/).